# PHP: Efficient way to store simple cache array in database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, caching, performance

Basically for a plugin for a dynamic site (site can be fairly large) I am caching results of some sort of search (because results are from an external search), the results can be 400-1500 characters in length.

As the results come in an array, I use `json_encode` (faster than serialize) to store in the database, but ~1.5KB per entry (since there may be 10,000)=15MB seems a little large for me.

My questions are:
* Is this an acceptable (your opinion) size per entry?
* Will running GZip or similar and storing in a `binary` field in MySQL be more efficient or take too much CPU time in the end? Anything normally used similar?

I prefer to not use memcached or alike as it's needed to be portable (but would that be better as well?) this is mostly a theory question for me, I just require input before I implement anything solid.

Comment: "15MB seems a little large for me." - Maybe, if you have to store that data in your watch (edit: oh no, not even then, see http://www.thinkgeek.com/interests/dads/9771/ ) . Or are there special requirements we don't know about yet?

Comment: A gigabyte of data is small if linearly used, but nitpicking parts of it many times per second is where I stop to think about anything larger than a few megabytes, although I'll assume it isn't actually slow like that.

Comment: Even then imo this leans on the premature optimization side. It should be fairly easy to implement this without optimization first, then stress test it and _then_ if and when you've _determined_ data size is the bottleneck add more or less transparent compression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will always be a CPU Cost for any kind of compression, it depends if you have the resources to handle it without any noticeable slowdown.
Space is cheap and abundant, so 15megs is ok.

But if you really want to compress your field, then check out Mysql's  [COMPRESS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_compress) and [UNCOMPRESS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_uncompress) functions.

This could be dropped into your code and it would work without changing any PHP/Logic.

Comment: Ah. I read MySQL `COMPRESS()` is slower than PHP using gzcompress, so I benchmarked gzcompress. 40,000 iterations `gzcompress(700kbstr, 1)` took 1.2 seconds and length resulted in 394KBs. `gzcompress(700kbstr, 9)` took 2.5 seconds and result was 388kbs. I'm sure using `UNHEX` in a `BINARY` field will make it smaller, I shall test. I'll accept this one because it looks the most promising. __EDIT:__ misworded that, you know what I mean.